# Having multiple issues getting images to appear in a MAUI library

Tags: android, image, svg, maui

Currently I'm trying to add a Dropbox icon to a MAUI library - not the app, a library which the app calls - and I'm following the example of the dotnet_bot svg which is included in the default MAUI app, and having all sorts of issues. Hoping someone knows how to fix one or more of these. There's a repo for a page I've been using for this testing at https://github.com/SmartmanApps/TestImagesPage

In summary, I can get the Dropbox svg working on Windows, when it's called dropboxicon.svg, but doesn't work on Android. dotnet_bot.svg works on all platforms UNLESS I call it something else - like dotnetbot.svg - in which case it doesn't work on EITHER platform. And if I rename dropboxicon.svg to dotnet_bot.svg that ALSO doesn't work.

Steps...
I created a new .NET 7 MAUI library (the above link), linked a test MAUI app to it and made it the MainPage, and tried all the following...

- as a control, I copied the default dotnet_bot.svg from the app's Resources/Images folder to the library's Resources/Images folder. When I have this set as the content of the page it works on both Windows and Android.
- at this point I changed the csproj reference to Images/dotnet_bot.svg to be Images/*, because I knew I was going to be doing some fiddling around with filenames, and was still working after that change.
- then I copied dropboxicon.svg into the Images folder and changed that to be the content of the page, and that works on Windows, but I only get a blank screen on Android.
- next, before doing any renaming of the dropbox svg, I renamed the bot one to dotnetbot.svg just to be sure renaming was going to work, and it was no longer working on either platform! That made me think it's getting the one that is defined at the App level, but then that doesn't make sense because my dropbox one wouldn't work at all in that case, and it does work on Windows. But it does make me think there's a hardcoded reference to dotnet_bot.svg that I'm missing somewhere, that my renamed version doesn't work.
- so then I renamed dotnet_bot.svg to dotnet_bot_old.svg and renamed dropboxicon.svg to dotnet_bot.svg, and now I was getting the Bot image, not the Dropbox image! So now I'm thinking there must be a cached dotnet_bot.svg somewhere in the system. No, doing a clean and rebuild did NOT fix this - anytime I rename the dropbox svg to be dotnet_bot, I get the dotnet bot image (so even after a clean and rebuild there must be a cached copy of it somewhere, but I don't know where).

Help?! Mainly I just want to get the Dropbox icon working on Android as well as Windows, but the shenanigans with the bot image show some much deeper rooted issues going on (it reminds me of what a pain it was to get my own image working as a splashscreen, which invovled having to use the original splashscreen name, but with my own image).

Edit: well, I DID have it working in Windows. After some more fiddling around now the dropbox image isn't working in Windows EITHER, even after I deleted the whole folder and recloned from my repo (sigh).

UPDATE: I ended up creating the test page from scratch again - https://github.com/SmartmanApps/TestImages - and got Windows working again. Android still doesn't, but I did find this open MAUI issue - https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8217 - does anyone know of any work-around? The dotnet_bot svg works but the dropbox one does not, and I don't know why it's throwing this error when the bot one does not.

FURTHER UPDATE: at this stage this is now confirmed to not be an issue with my code, and yet still not working on my machine. Hoping someone might know why it's not working on my machine? I'm on VS 17.7.3, .NET 7 library/app, Xamarin Android 13.2.1.2, and MAUI 7.0.92

Comment: You should be using "dotnet_bot.png" instead of "dotnet_bot.svg".

Comment: Yes, in the library it is - the files themselves are svg.

Comment: Your case is interesting to me, see my answer, do what It says, and if you still have a problem, we can talk more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I copied the repository, and created a simple test project to consume it.

If we open your dropboxicon.svg, in the repository you linked, we see:

```
width="2500" height="2329"
```

This produces this exception, when trying to draw it in Android platform.

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Canvas: trying to draw too large...

You need to resize your SVG, make it smaller.
Right now this is the main problem consuming your lib.

Edit: Just tested it again, after you reduced your dropbox image to lower size, everything is working on Android as well.

[image]

As you can see from the low resolution 40x40 is just as bad choice as 2500x2500.

You should go with something acceptable in between.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I'm not getting that message. I switched off "Just my code" and still not getting it. I switched on to break for that exception, still not getting it. I'm not sure why you're getting that message and I'm not?

I did find "file not found" messages for it, but not sure if that's because of the size of the file. It's in exactly the same place as dotnet_bot.svg, which it finds no problem.

Comment: Note: I found how to resize the image, but still saying not found. I went back to Windows, and as per my earlier edit to the question, it's not working in Windows either, even though it was initially. I think I need to first try and find out why it's stopped working in Windows, then turn my attention to Android. At the moment I have no idea why it's stopped working in Windows - I already tried importing the original image and that didn't work. P.S. I'm not getting any error messages at all when I run it in Windows, but I just get a blank screen.

Comment: @donaldp I used the very same lib you posted. I cloned the repository, and just added maui project to consume it. (As project reference). On windows the dropbox icon showed, on android I got the exception above. Everything seems fine to me, besides the image size...

Comment: Yeah I had it working on Windows initially too, but no matter what I've tried so far I don't get the error message you got, nor any error message for it not working on Windows now, and obviously it's pretty important to get error messages. ;-) Maybe I need to do a repair of VS or something - not sure why we're getting different behaviour. Oh, BTW what version of VS are you using?

Comment: I recreated the library from scratch and got it working again on Windows, but dropbox svg doesn't work on Android, still. I found an open MAUI issue for it, but doesn't have any work-arounds. See my update to the question.

Comment: I will get back on you, when I get my hands on the PC again, and test it. The version is 17.6.something. The version of MAUI is 7.0.86.

Comment: @donaldp Tested it again, just replaced the modified low-res svg you provided. Everything is working fine.

Comment: You mean you replaced it with a different svg, or you did something to the Dropbox svg to make it high res? The dotnet_bot svg has always worked, I just don't know how to make the Dropbox svg work

Comment: I cloned your lib with VS. Then I made a project, and set "project reference" to your lib. Made the only page in the shell to be the page in your lib. Win worked fine. Android threw exception, because 2500x2500 svg. Then you updated your question, and put a link with 40x40 svg.  I replaced it in the original lib, and everything worked fine. If you have a problem, it is not in your code.

Comment: See here, your first file: https://github.com/SmartmanApps/TestImagesPage/blob/master/TestImagesPage/Resources/Images/dropboxicon.svg?short_path=155c67c width="2500" height="2329", does not work. Your second file: https://github.com/SmartmanApps/TestImages/blob/master/TestImages/Resources/Images/dropbox1.svg?short_path=0cb821a width="25" height="23" - works perfectly. Thou the size makes it look terrible.

Comment: I made it that small in an attempt to get it to work on Android, which it still doesn't for me (I presume you mean on Android?), so again we're running into it works on your machine and not mine. Don't really know what is going on there. P.S. but thanks for confirming not a code issue (now I just need to find what the ACTUAL issue is).

Comment: I see now you edited your answer to say yes working on Android. I'll accept your answer eventually, but I want to leave it as unanswered for the moment in case someone else sees it and knows why this isn't working on my machine.

Comment: I've accepted your answer now - still couldn't get it to work, and I've switched to using FontAwesome instead now (in fact, I tried using the FontAwesome Dropbox svg, and couldn't get THAT one to work either! So fonts it is then...).

Comment: @donaldp I updated my studio. Everything works. Can you build apk, and upload it somewhere?